# $\frac{1}{a^2+1} + \frac{1}{b^2+1} \geq min(1;\frac{2}{ab+1})$

Tags: inequality

Let: $a,b \geq 0$. Prove that:

$$\frac{1}{a^2+1} + \frac{1}{b^2+1} \geq min(1;\frac{2}{ab+1})$$

I so confuse here, I can prove this: $$\frac{1}{a^2+1} + \frac{1}{b^2+1} \geq \frac{2}{ab+1}$$

which required $ab \geq 1$, but I'm still thinking about the other cases, like $LHS > 1,5; 1,1; 1,2$. And when it $ \geq  1$. Can anyone helps me please? Thanks you!!

Answer (score 4):

As you stated, for $ab \ge 1$, the minimum value on the RHS becomes $\frac{2}{ab+1}$. Since $\frac{1}{a^2+1}+\frac{1}{b^2+1}=\frac{a^2+b^2+2}{a^2b^2+a^2+b^2+1}$, we get that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{a^2+b^2+2}{a^2b^2+a^2+b^2+1} & \geq\frac{2}{ab+1} \\
(ab+1)(a^2+b^2+2) & \geq 2(a^2b^2+a^2+b^2+1) \\
a^3b+ab^3+2ab+a^2+b^2+2 & \geq 2a^2b^2+2a^2+2b^2+2 \\
a^3b-2a^2b^2+ab^3+2ab-a^2-b^2 & \geq 0 \\
ab(a^2-2ab+b^2)-(a^2-2ab+b^2) & \geq 0 \\
(ab-1)(a-b)^2 & \geq 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Since $ab\ge 1\;\to\; ab-1\geq 0$ and $(a-b)^2\geq 0$, the end result above is true. Note the operations between all of the lines are reversible (i.e., there's an implicit $\iff$ between each line), so we can do the opposite operations to go from the last line to the first one to get the desired result.

Instead, with $ab \le 1$ (i.e., $1 \geq ab$), the minimum value on the RHS then becomes $1$. Using $a, b \ge 0 \;\to\; ab \ge 0$, we have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{a^2+b^2+2}{a^2b^2+a^2+b^2+1} & \geq 1 \\
a^2+b^2+2 & \geq a^2b^2+a^2+b^2+1 \\
1 & \geq a^2b^2 \\
1 & \geq ab
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

As before, the operations between each line above is reversible, so going from the last line to the first, we would then get what we were trying to prove. Thus, this proves the question inequality holds for all cases, so it's always true.

Comment: You could also compute
$$ 
\frac{1}{a^2+1} + \frac{1}{b^2+1} - \frac{2}{ab+1} = \frac{(a-b)^2(ab-1)}{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(ab+1)} \ge 0
$$
for the first case, and
$$
\frac{1}{a^2+1} + \frac{1}{b^2+1} - 1 = \frac{(ab+1)(1-ab)}{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)} \ge 0
$$
for the second case, that saves you from arguing whether the operations are reversible or not. It is of course equivalent to your argument.